# How to append object to a json file with JSR 353 (Java API for JSON Processing)

Tags: java, json, append, stream-processing, jsr-353

Using JSR-353 (https://jsonp.java.net/index.html)
I would like to open a json file and append some object in the root array, eg :

```
[{"foo":"bar"}]
```

I would like with a code about like this :

```
try(JsonGenerator writer = Json.createGenerator(new FileOutputStream(this.file))){
    writer.writeStartObject().write("hello", "world").writeEnd();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And obtain in the end :

```
[
    {"foo":"bar"},
    {"hello":"world"}
]
```

Note : I don't want to have to load the full json in-memory to append my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note : I don't want to have to load the full json in-memory to append
>   my data.

Basically, you can't. You would have to parse the full data structure, so that your `write(..)` would know where to write. Otherwise, it's just appending somewhere and that might break the JSON format.

So read the JSON from the file, generate a `JsonArray` from it. Create a new `JsonObject` from your values. Add it to the array. Then write the full array.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply "append".  In the general case you must read in the JSON, modify the tree-structured memory image, then "serialize" it back to linear JSON.

In very simple cases such as the above you could in theory seek to the end, backspace over the closing `]`, then write out `,`, the second object, and a new closing `]`, but it's not a general solution to updating JSON.